# Find if all letters in a string are unique

Tags: ruby, string, character, unique

I need to know if all letters in a string are unique. For a string to be unique, a letter can only appear once. If all letters in a string are distinct, the string is unique. If one letter appears multiple times, the string is not unique.

```
"Cwm fjord veg balks nth pyx quiz."
# => All 26 letters are used only once. This is unique

"This is a string"
# => Not unique, i and s are used more than once

"two"
# => unique, each letter is shown only once
```

I tried writing a function that determines whether or not a string is unique.

```
def unique_characters(string)
  for i in ('a'..'z')
  if string.count(i) > 1
    puts "This string is unique"
  else
    puts "This string is not unique"
  end
end

unique_characters("String")
```

I receive the output

```
"This string is unique" 26 times.
```

Edit:

I would like to humbly apologize for including an incorrect example in my OP. I did some research, trying to find pangrams, and assumed that they would only contain 26 letters. I would also like to thank you guys for pointing out my error. After that, I went on wikipedia to find a perfect pangram (I wrongly thought the others were perfect).

Here is the link for reference purposes

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pangrams#Perfect_pangrams_in_English_.2826_letters.29

Once again, my apologies.

Comment: Question is not clear. In the first example you claim to be unique, the space character is not unique. And, what is your question?

Comment: I meant letters instead of characters

Comment: `o` is present in your first example 4 times...

Comment: In what sense is the first example unique? `"e"` appears three times.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I made a mistake there. I have edited the example to provide something different. Once again, I apologize, I was clearly in the wrong. That was my mistake

Comment: I'm really looking forward to Episode 7.  Can you tell us if there will be an 8?

Comment: I think giving the Wiki link is only confusing, as you are not asking if a string is a pangram; that is, you are not requiring "unique" strings to contain all letters of the alphabet.  Also, your choice of the term "unique strings" is not a good one, as that term already has an unambiguous meaning.

Comment: @George, your edit confused me more than it clarified anything - you are looking for a perfect pangram or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
.downcase
("a".."z").all?{|c| s.count(c) <= 1}
# => false
```

Another way to do it is:

```
s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
(s.downcase !~ /([a-z]).*\1/)
# => false
```

Comment: Not that it matters with small strings, but: `count` O(n) `all?` O(n) -> O(n^2). The problem is conceptually O(n).

Comment: @tokland I don't think your estimate is right. You are confusing two things: on one hand, your `n` is 26, which is actually a constant, and should not contribute to complexity. On the other hand, your `n` represents the string length. Actually, my answer is `O(n)`.

Comment: Rover wants to know why it's never the "quick brown dog" and "lazy fox".

Answer (score 4):

I would solve this in two steps: 1) extract the letters 2) check if there are duplicates:

```
letters = string.scan(/[a-z]/i)        # append .downcase to ignore case
letters.length == letters.uniq.length
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that does not convert the string to an array:

```
def dupless?(str)
  str.downcase.each_char.with_object('') { |c,s|
    c =~ /[a-z]/ && s.include?(c) ? (return false) : s << c }
  true
end

dupless?("Cwm fjord veg balks nth pyx quiz.") #=> true
dupless?("This is a string.")                 #=> false
dupless?("two")                               #=> true
dupless?("Two tubs")                          #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually keep track of the duplicate characters:

```
def is_unique?(string)
  # Remove whitespaces
  string = string.gsub(/\s+/, "")

  # Build a hash counting all occurences of each characters
  h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] =  0 }
  string.chars.each { |c| h[c] += 1 }

  # An array containing all the repetitions
  res = h.keep_if {|k, c| c > 1}.keys

  if res.size == 0
    puts "All #{string.size} characters are used only once. This is unique"
  else
    puts "Not unique #{res.join(', ')} are used more than once"
  end
end

is_unique?("This is a string") # Not unique i, s are used more than once
is_unique?("two") # All 3 characters are used only once. This is unique
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_uniq_letters?(str)
  letters = str.gsub(/[^A-Za-z]/, '').chars
  letters == letters.uniq
end
```

If this doesn't have to be case sensitive,

```
def has_uniq_letters?(str)
  letters = str.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '').chars
  letters == letters.uniq
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string is unique or not, you can try out this:

```
string_input.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '').split("").sort.join('') == ('a' .. 'z').to_a.join('')
```

This will return true, if all the characters in your string are unique and if they include all the 26 characters.

Comment: This gives a wrong result when there is an underscore.

Comment: Sorry @YedhuKrishnan  I noticed that, too.  After I wrote the comment.  So I deleted it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check underscore. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Counting duplicates manually is completely unnecessary.

Just convert the string to an array of chars and then compare it to the same array of chars after using the #uniq method on it.

```
string = "my nice words"
string.delete!(" ")
string.chars == string.chars.uniq ? :all_letters_unique! : :repeated_letters
```

Before comparing, spaces are removed so they won't count as repetitions.